# How to check for a certain Status Code (4xx) in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

What I want is: stop the program until status code 412 appears and then proceed.
I have the following code to check for the status code 412:

```
  - name: Check if plan was applied
    uri:
      url: "https://website.some.url.com/api/v1/clusters/elasticsearch/{{elasticClusterDetails.elastic$
      method: GET
      user: admin
      password: "{{rootpw.stdout}}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: no
    register: result
    until: result.status == 412
    retries: 20
    delay: 30
```

After a few retries I get

> ERROR: [...] status was 412 not 200

So the 412 actually comes up but is not recognized as fulfillment of the 'until' condition and the program exits. 
From my understanding, the request can't be made when the code switches from 200 to 412. 
What do I need to change to not getting an error at Code 412?

Please NOTE: This is no duplicate because checking for 4xx status code is different than to check for 2xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for the [uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/uri_module.html), and you'll see that there is a `status_code` attribute that can be used to specify one or more status codes that are considered "successful". So something like (assuming that you expect to receive either a `200` or `412` response):

```
- name: Check if plan was applied
  uri:
    url: "https://website.some.url.com/api/v1/clusters/elasticsearch/{{elasticClusterDetails.elastic$
    method: GET
    user: admin
    password: "{{rootpw.stdout}}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: no
    status_code: [200,412]
  register: result
  until: result.status == 412
  retries: 20
  delay: 30
```

The problem you have right now is that the 412 status code is considered a failure.

You could also set `ignore_errors: true` on the task, but using the `status_code` attribute is probably better, because it still allows the task to failure in the event you receive unexpected status codes.

**NB**: The docs say, "can also be a comma-separated list of status codes", but the source looks like it expects an actual YAML list. So you may need to tweak the value depending on which value actually works.